# Does tmpfs automatically resize when the amount RAM changes, and does it compete when there's multiple tmpfs?

Tags: linux, ram, tmpfs

If I have a tmpfs set to 50%, and later on I add or remove RAM, does tmpfs automatically adjust its partition size?

Also what if I have multiple tmpfs each set at 50%. Do multiple tmpfs compete against each other for the same 50%? How is this managed by the OS?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you mount a `tmpfs` instance with a percentage it will take the percent size of the systems **physical ram**. For instance, if you have 2gb of physical ram and you mount a `tmpfs` with 50%, your `tmpfs` will have a size of 1gb. In your scenario, you add physical ram to your system, let's say another 2gb, that your system has 4gb of physical ram. When mounting the tmpfs it will have a size of 2gb now.

When mounting multiple instances of `tmpfs` each with 50% set, it will work. If `both tmpfs` instances were filled completely, the system will swap out the lesser used pages. If swap space is full too, you will have `No space left on device` errors.

**Edit**:

`tmpfs` only uses the amount of memory that is taken, not the full 50%. So, if only 10mb of those 1gb are taken, your `tmpfs` instance only occupies those 10mb. It's not not reserved, it's dynmically. With multiple instances of 50%, the first one that need memory gets memory. The system swapps the lesser used pages, if 50% is occupied or not. The `tmpfs` instance is not aware of the fact whether it uses physical ram or swap space. You can mount a `tmpfs` of 100gb if you want and it will work.

I assume that you shut the system down before adding ram. So the `tmpfs` is remounted at startup anyway. If you add ram while the system runs, you will **fry the ram**, the motherboard and most likely your hand. I can't really recommand that :-)

**Sources**:

- [Kernel Documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/tmpfs.txt)

Comment: If there are multiple instances of tmpfs at 50%, do they all equally share the 50%, or do the percentages add up?

Also do I need to remount the tmpfs to take advantage of the new RAM? Or does it automatically adjust?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai see my edit

Comment: But there are ways to hot add ram, I'm more referring to servers, not personal desktops.

Comment: Ok here's an example, if there are 2 tmpfs with both 50% (1 gb each). If the first has 1gb filled up (assume no paging for simplicity), does that mean the 2nd tmpfs has no more space, since the first tmpfs has already filled up the total 50% share?

Comment: I don't know if it adjusts automatically. I would do a remount/resize. I case of your second question (no swap) the `tmpfs` will still have plenty of free disk space, and your machine will crash.

Comment: I still don't understand. If there are 2 tmpfs each with 50%. This obviously doesn't mean that the tmpfs each get their own half of the ram. This would mean 2 tmpfs can fill up 100% of the ram. They must be sharing the 50% right?

Comment: Yes, tmpfs has a limit of 50% physical ram **total**. All tmpfs instances can fill at most 50% of the physical ram. But, if you have swap space it's not a problem. Without swap it can lead to a crash.

Comment: See it's possible to "hot add" ram to VMs without restarting. http://serverfault.com/questions/384184/adding-ram-to-a-virtual-machine-without-restart